# echo MySql column names and values

Tags: php

What I need is to have a list name => value to be able to make MySql queries. My problem is, I can access MySql records, but I also need to access table's column names, what should I change in my code?

Thanks

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM test_table";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Erro!: " . mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if(is_array($row)) {
        foreach ($row as $col => $val) {
            echo $col." = ".$val."<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

ok, so now why can't I join the values to then make my sql queries?

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        foreach ($row as $col => $val) {
            $colunas .= join(",",$col);
            $valores .= join(",",$val);
        }
        echo "colunas = ".$col."<br>";
        echo "valores = ".$val."<br>";
    }
```

I just get empty colunas and valores

Thanks, sorry if it seems to easy, but I'm lost

Comment: I think some books or manuals can be useful in beginning of studying. Maybe http://dev.mysql.com/doc/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You needs `while` loop and a call to `mysql_fetch_assoc`

```
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {   
        foreach ($row as $col => $val) {
            echo $col." = ".$val."<br>";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

use  `mysql_fetch_assoc`,

see : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

Answer (score 2):

I think you mixed up some variable names, and, you don't need the join function, since you're adding one column name at a time. does this work?

```
$colunas=$valores="";

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        foreach ($row as $col => $val) {
            $colunas .= $col.',';
            $valores .= $val.',';
        }
        echo "colunas = ".$colunas."<br>";
        echo "valores = ".$valores."<br>";
```